# Custom Validator on Custom Form

Tags: 8, forms

I see all kinds of examples of how to add a custom validator to an "existing form." Which means, you would use hook_form_alter. I want to add one in the code for my custom form.

I'm adding this in my buildForm():

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'mycustom_form_validate';
```

However, that function never seems to get called. I know naming the validation function "validateForm()" would make it work automatically. But I want to specifically call this validation function because things are going to get more complex. But I seem stuck on this baby step.

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#attributes']['novalidate'] = 'novalidate';
    $form['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
    $form['#action'] = '#email_subscription';
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mycustom_form_validate';

    $form['fname'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('First Name'),
      '#maxlength' => 255,
      '#size' => 64,
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#required_error' => 'Please provide your first name.',
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('send'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function mycustom_form_validate(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $valid = $this->validateEmail($form, $form_state);
    if (!$valid) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('email', $this->t('Invalid email address.'));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the line to:

```
$form['#validate'][] = '::mycustom_form_validate';
```

Drupal has special handling for that `::` prefix (see [`FormState::prepareCallback`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AprepareCallback/8.7.x)), and processes the above to an equivalent [callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) of:

```
[$form_object, 'mycustom_form_validate']
```

Which will correctly resolve to your custom method.

Comment: That got it. Thank you for the explanation.